# Get Grid Id from onSelectAll event in jQGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

We are generating the jQGrid dynamically and providing an dynamic Id for the grid. Currently my requirement is to find the grid Id in the onSelectAll Event. Based on the Grid Id I'm creating new events.I tried all the possible ways but not able to get the Grid Id. Please help someone help me in resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please share your code and your tried code.

Answer (score 0):

All callbacks of jqGrid, inclusive `onSelectAll` will be called with `this` initialized to the DOM of the grid (the main `<table>` element). Thus you can use `this.id` or `this.p.id` to get the id of the grid.

It's strictly recommended that you include in every question the information about the version of jqGrid, which you use, the fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). Moreover it's strictly recommended to post the JavaScript code, which you use or at least the fragment of the code (the code of `onSelectAll` callback for example). In some cases the problem exists because of wrong usage of the JavaScript, which follows, for example, that `this` value will be discarded.